# Azure DevOpsでOrganizationにあるすべてのwork itemを網羅したチャートを作りたい

Tags: azure

Azure DevOpsでProject内で作成したwork itemに関するチャートを作成するには、Queryの検索を利用すればできますが
この範囲を広げてあるOrganizationに含まれるすべての work itemを網羅したチャート作成するにはどうすればよいでしょうか?

最終的に入手したいチャートは、あるOrganizationに所属するメンバーやチームに割り当てられているwork itemのうちactive状態のwork itemを対象にしたヒストグラムです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました
Queryを作成するときに「Query Across Projects」オプションを有効にして、「Team Project」フィールドの条件に対象となるプロジェクト名をIn条件で追加することで可能になりました

下記参考サイトの「Query across projects」の項目が公式ドキュメントになります
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#across-projects